# How do I remove the landing dashboard from the dashboard list in grafana?

Tags: json, grafana, grafana-templating

I want to create a panel that shows all the dashboards. This panel is created in another dashboard which I don't want to be present in the list, and it(the dashboard which I want to be absent) is the landing page, starred.

I tried editing the JSON but could not understand to go through/around it.

The panel JSON is:

```
{
  "cacheTimeout": null,
  "description": "A service status dashboard for ZCash Ongoing Services",
  "folderId": null,
  "gridPos": {
    "h": 12,
    "w": 12,
    "x": 12,
    "y": 8
  },
  "headings": false,
  "id": 2,
  "limit": 10,
  "links": [],
  "options": {},
  "query": "",
  "recent": false,
  "search": true,
  "starred": false,
  "tags": [],
  "timeFrom": null,
  "timeShift": null,
  "title": "ZEC Service Status Dashboard",
  "type": "dashlist"
}
```

As of now, the panel looks like this:
[image: Current panel]. And this is in the dashboard: "ZCash service status dashboard". I want this dashboard to be removed from the dashboard list shown here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by having the landing dashboard in a separate folder.

Go to Settings of your landing dashboard and click on the dropdown list next to the `Folder` option under `General`. Now, click on the option `-- New Folder --`, give a name for your new folder and click <kbd>Create</kbd>.

Now, modify the `folderId` attribute in your panel JSON to have value `0` (assuming you have 2 folders and the landing dashboard which you don't want to be present in the list is present in the second folder), or go the `Options` tab in the edit section of your panel and select the folder from the dropdown list which contains all dashboards except the landing dashboard. This will give you a panel that shows all the dashboards except the dashboard it is created in.

Comment: can you also take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58581186/how-can-i-place-home-dashboard-as-the-top-in-list-of-dashboards-in-grafana

Comment: Sure, I will try.