# How can I place home dashboard as the top in list of dashboards in Grafana?

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

I want to place the home dashboard at the top when the user clicks on the dashboard expandable list. I have a dashboard that is set as my home and called as "Home" but while navigating, it is a bad UX to see it at the bottom of the list. To explain with pictures:

The following two pictures depict what I currently have:
[image: Home dashboard is the landing page, which is perfectly fine]

[image: Currently, the list does not place Home at the top]

This is what I want:
[image: Home is always at the top]

I tried looking into multiple options of placing dashboards at the top: starred, etc but none seemed relevant. I tried to compare what is the difference between my dashboard and statoshi.info and found one: it seems that dashboard is using the Home property of Grafana, and hence that page as an icon of home. But, I could not find how to do this?

Comment: How many starred dashboards do you have?

Comment: Hey, no, I don't have any starred dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

One way to place a dashboard at the top when the user clicks on the dashboard expandable list is to make the concerned dashboard as the only starred dashboard. Starring a dashboard is like pinning it to the top of the list.

When the user clicks on the dashboard expandable list, the Starred dashboards, if any, are shown alphabetically at the top, followed by the Recent dashboards, if any, and then all dashboards are shown alphabetically under their folder name.

If there are 2 or more starred dashboards then they will be arranged alphabetically and it is not guaranteed that the home dashboard named "Home" will be at the top of this list. Thus, it is necessary to only have a single starred dashboard that you want to place at the top.

Comment: Hi, I have only one dashboard in the general folder starred, i.e. Home. Even then, it doesn't appear on the top. In fact, there is no starred section in the expandable list. It starts with 'Recent' and then the usual grouping.

Comment: It's strange! In my case, it starts with 'Starred', followed by 'Recent' and then the usual grouping. I can't find any way to alter this order.

Comment: I can see the starred dashboard for me, when I am logged in. 
But if I open the dashboard anonymously, there's no starred dashboard. I think it has to do something with making a dashboard starred for all.